# Delete data returned from subquery in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have two tables. if the data in table1 is more than a predefined limit (say 2), i need to copy the remaining contents of table1 to table2 and delete those same contents from table1.

I used the below query to insert the excess data from table1 to table2.

```
 insert into table2 
  SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ROWNUM < ((select count(*) from table1)-2);
```

Now i need the delete query to delete the above contents from table1.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks Tony.I tried the below delete query, but it deletes the entire set of records in table1.                                                                                          delete from TABLEA  where exists (SELECT * FROM TABLEA  WHERE ROWNUM <((select count(*) from TableA )-2));

Comment: You have no guarantees on the order of the records in the resultset your query. It is an absoute no-go to mirror the `insert` statement's query in a subsequent `delete` as both queries very well produce different resut sets.

Comment: If you have partitioning available, you might be able to archive like this at the partition or subpartition level.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward approach would be an interim storage in a temporary table. Its content can be used to determine the data to be deleted from `table1` as well as the source to feed table 2.
    Assume (slightly abusing notation)  to be the PK column (or that of any candidate key) of `table1` - usually there'll be some key that comprises only 1 column.

```
create global temporary table t_interim as
   ( SELECT <pk> pkc FROM table1 WHERE ROWNUM < ((select count(*) from table1)-2 )
;

insert into table2 
   select * from table1 where <pk> IN (
    select pkc from t_interim
);

delete from table1 where <pk> IN (
    select pkc from t_interim
);
```

**Alternative**

If any key of `table1` spans more than 1 column, use an `EXISTS` clause instead as follows ( denoting the i-th component of a candidate key in `table1`):

```
create global temporary table t_interim as
   ( SELECT <ck_1> ck1, <ck_2> ck2, ..., <ck_n> ckn FROM table1 WHERE ROWNUM < ((select count(*) from table1)-2 )
;

insert into table2 
   select * from table1 t
    where exists (
             select 1
               from t_interim t_i
              where t.ck_1 = t_i.ck1
                and t.ck_2 = t_i.ck2
                    ...
                and t.ck_n = t_i.ckn
          )
        ;

delete from table1 t where
    where exists (
             select 1
               from t_interim t_i
              where t.ck_1 = t_i.ck1
                and t.ck_2 = t_i.ck2
                    ...
                and t.ck_n = t_i.ckn
          )
        ;
```

(Technically you could try to adjust the first scheme by synthesizing a key from the components of any CK, eg. by concatenating. You run the risk of introducing ambiguities ( (`a bc`, `ab c`) -> (`abc`, `abc`) ) or run into implementation limits ( max. varchar length ) using the first method)

**Note**
In case the table doesn't have a PK, you can apply the technique using any *candidate key* of `table1`. There will always be one, in the extreme case it's the set of all columns.

This situation may be the right time to improve the db design and add a (synthetic) pk column to table1 ( and any other tables in the system that lack it).

Comment: Our table doesnt have a primary key so not able to use the IN clause.

Comment: @Neel: Your table _does_ have an (implicit) primary key: The set of all columns. Btw, this may be the time to improve the db design and add a (synthetic) pk column to `table1` ( and any other tables in your system ).